# Intellisense stops working after modifying includes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense

Good evening all,
I currently have a source which behaves very unusually and I am completely stumped as to why.

The issue:
When initially opening the source, the project includes and libraries are broken
[This path does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgG7s.png)

However, when I attempt to amend this issue by removing the broken directories, Intellisense stops working. This is obviously a problem because Intellisense is pog. [Stops working after path change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XQxH.png)

I have never seen this before and I have spent quite a while try to fix it but with no success, here are some of the things I have tried:

1. Including the rest of the DX9 files I needed
2. Trying Visual Studio 17, 19, and 22
3. Updating SDK and VS to latest versions
4. Resetting VS preferences

Also, Yes it is turned on, it breaks as soon as I change anything

I hope someone knows how to fix this thx

Edit: Here is a gif showing it in action: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzJw0.gif

Comment: No one has enough fingers to count the number of bugs in MS Intellisense.  What really matters, and what you should check first, is: does the code compile?

Comment: lmao true. I can compile after replacing the directories. However, intellisense still fails to work.

Comment: What does the error message prompt? Without including a new valid path, only removing an invalid path then the error disappears? Did you also check the Property > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories, as I saw the red wavy underlines under `#include ...` from the gif.